# Python pip is messed up

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to run uninstall flask 0.9.1 to install 0.9.0 instead because i get the error

```
  ascii_attachments = current_app.extensions['mail'].ascii_attachments
```

KeyError: 'mail'

and i read from this post= '[Python Flask Email KeyError KeyError: 'mail'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466384/python-flask-email-keyerror-keyerror-mail)'

that this was the solution

```
Error: The file/path provided (routes) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
```

so I checked pip and I got this error:

```
bash: usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

I thought it might be due to the cash, so I typed:

```
hash -r
```

however, the same problem occurs afterward.
Any ideas on what I can do?

EDIT:

whenver i type:

```
$ which pip
```

i get this directory back:
    /usr/local/bin/pip

Comment: `usr/local/bin/pip` seems to be missing a leading `/`.

Comment: should I alias it as something else? Or how can i change the name?

Comment: Flask doesn't need pip in order to run

Comment: How can i fix my path to pip?

Comment: I apologize the error from flask was an input error

Comment: Can you please show `echo $PATH`? If you run `/usr/local/bin/pip` yourself, what happens?

Comment: /home/kristoffer/bin:/home/kristoffer/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin

Comment: I have no idea, why it is liking java dependencies

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pip`?

Comment: @Lane Terry: yes whenever i do this, it lists the correct directory 
    Usage:   
  /usr/bin/python -m pip <command> [options]

Comment: What OS and version? Are you running the flask app as root or the local user? Also, the problem should be able to be resolved by `python -m pip uninstall flask-mail && python -m pip install flask-mail==0.9.0` correct?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, yes i'm calling the export command and running flask run

Comment: Assuming pip isn't on the root user's path, causing the issue `bash: usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory`. Run the commands I put in the edit above as root and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: this would work if i ran it it as a sudo command. However after installing some of the dependencies i get this error:

Comment: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_mail.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: @kristheman See above. If you need to run the flask app as root, install the packages as root. If not, install using --user as mentioned. I suggest researching virtualenv if you're having trouble handling these issues.

Comment: Should i use a virtualenv for this? I mean even if i run as sudo i still get an error, telling my to use the --user argument?

Comment: I don't see a reason why your root user would be unable to access that path. You can try `chown root:root /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_mail.py`, but again, if you don't have a decent grasp of how to manage a Linux instance virtualenv is going to make your life easier. Running that command could break some things for the local user, so replacing `root:root` with `user:group` is preferable.